# Javascripts not working after postback

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with bootstrap components on a asp.net web application.
It's works fine, but curiously, they stop working after a page postback. The appearance is fine, but the behavior isn't. That's why i supose that the problem envolves the javascript files.

For example, a dorp down button: after postback, the expand action doesn't work.

Do you have an idea what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Did you check the javascript console to see if there are any javascript errors? That's the first place I would look.

Comment: Hi @Dan Herman! There are no errors. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are using an UpdatePanel to do a partial page refresh, then when the contents of the panel are updated via AJAX, the usual `$(document).ready(...) / $(...)` stuff does not fire again, which means that the custom JS functionality (like the dropdowns) that is part of Bootstrap does not get re-bound to the new elements.

What I usually do is extract my code that sets up the javascript event handlers and behaviour into their own function (e.g. `function BindEvents() { ... }`), and then I use the following code inside the update panel to ensure it gets re-run *after* the partial postback (as well as on the initial page load):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.Application.add_load(BindEvents);
</script>
```

**EDIT:** Here is a suggested basic `BindEvents()` function that should re-initialise the dropdowns for you:

```
function BindEvents() {
    $('[data-toggle=dropdown]').dropdown();
    // other bootstrap binding code - see the combined Bootstrap.js for ideas
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm pretty sure that's what's happening. I'm using a update panel, as you said. But what exactly setup the javascripts event handlers on function BindEvents() { ... } ?

Comment: Are you using any custom javascript to enable the dropdown button behaviours, or are you just setting the `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute on it, which "automatically" seems to work?

Comment: Also, are you using the latest version of jQuery and Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: I'm just setting the `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute. And yes, i'm using the latest version of jQuery and twitter bootstrap as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: @LeandroFaria I added a small sample that should re-enable the dropdowns for you. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It worked perfeclty!! Thank you very much.

Comment: How can I use this with Bootstrap Switch

Comment: @VijayKumbhoje Ensure that your Bootstrap Switch initialisation code (e.g. `$('.my-checkboxes').bootstrapSwitch()`) is inside a function that `BindEvents()` calls.

Comment: @GregL Its working I have cascading dropdowns after first postbacks my next dropdown causing problem in postback. The data is not loading in next dropdown. what you will suggest. Thanks

Comment: @VijayKumbhoje I don't have sufficient details to give any good suggestions, sorry. I suggest you write up a question with all the relevant details and link me to it.

Comment: Works perfect! i've added $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); line and fixed my problem!

Answer (score 2):

If you use this line of code, anything in the endRequestHandler should fire everytime an update panel updates.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);

        function endRequestHandler(){

             // initialize controls here...

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing the following in the body of a page solved the issue:

`<script type="text/javascript">`
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
`</script>`