# Bootstrap: dynamically created dropdown is closed after clicking on any item in it

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have the page which contains a dynamically created [dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)(the piece of HTML code is injected to the page after AJAX-call). After AJAX-call I can open the dropdown(clicking on special anchor), but I can't click on any element in the dropdown(for example, set a focus to some textbox inside the dropdown) - after clicking dropdown is closed.

If I add the same layout to the static part of the page then a dropdown works as expected.

I have found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238650/javascripts-not-working-after-postback) and tried to re-init the dropdowns using function `$('[data-toggle=dropdown]').dropdown();` (I ran it in FireBug's console), but without any success.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used following script in callback-function after AJAX-call:

```
$('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-menu').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Cam be useful for somebody.